# Listener to drawableTop of TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, ontouchlistener

Need to handle click event on `drawableTop` of `TextView`, written following code,

```
    tvSocialMedia.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() <= tvSocialMedia.getTotalPaddingTop()) {
                    // your action for drawable click event
                    tvEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.email,0, 0);
                    tvPhone.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.phone,0, 0);
                    tvAddress.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.address,0, 0);
                    tvSocialMedia.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.social_media_select,0, 0);
                    usage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.social_media));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But code inside `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)` is not getting executed. Correct me if I have written wrong condition in if statement.

Comment: question is bit unclear to me :| whats the view you are using to call `onClickSocial`

Comment: onClickSocial is a method to handle TextView click(R.id.tvSocialMedia)

Comment: What is the meaning to write `setOnTouchListener` into `onClickSocial`. You are setting `onTouch` event when `textview` is clicked.

Comment: So `event.getRawX() <= tvSocialMedia.getTotalPaddingTop()` this condition does not returning true?

Comment: if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) is not returning true, also tried MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Comment: I don't know what going on but why don't you use GestureDetector. like [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**changes to handle event on drawableTop:**

> 1) from `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)` to
>   `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)`
>
> 2)from `if(event.getRawX() <= tvSocialMedia.getTotalPaddingTop())` to
>   `if(event.getRawY() >= tvPhone.getTop() -
>   tvPhone.getTotalPaddingTop())`
>
> 3) return false

```
tvPhone.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(event.getRawY() >= tvPhone.getTop() - tvPhone.getTotalPaddingTop()) {
                    // your action for drawable click event
                    tvEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.email,0, 0);
                    tvPhone.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.phone_select,0, 0);
                    tvAddress.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.address,0, 0);
                    tvSocialMedia.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.social_media,0, 0);
                    usage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.phone_no));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```